# Using Akka Http for Multiple Bindings

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Using akka http to bind to a port and then route incoming connections is easy enough given the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/http/introduction.html).

One question not addressed is how to bind multiple ports for different routes.  If I have multiple specifications:

```
val route1 : Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse,_] = ???
val interface1 : String = ???
val port1 : Int = ???

val route2 : Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse,_] = ???
val interface2 : String = ???
val port2 : Int = ???
```

Should these be bound with one [`HttpExt`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/?_ga=1.42089507.723935664.1469018756#akka.http.scaladsl.HttpExt)?

```
implicit val actorSystem : akka.actor.ActorSystem = ???

val httpExt = akka.http.scaladsl.Http()

httpExt.bindAndHandle(route1, interface1, port1)
httpExt.bindAndHandle(route2, interface2, port2)
```

Or, should a different `HttpExt` be used for each bind?

```
Http().bindAndHandle(route1, interface1, port1)
Http().bindAndHandle(route2, interface2, port2)
```

If either is valid, then are there any implications for using one method over the other?

Thank you in advance for your review and response.

Comment: This will answet your question:  Http() eq Http()

Comment: @viktorklang That does add some clarity to the question.  But, if an invocation of `Http ()` has any side effects, e.g. on the `ActorSystem`, then object equality wouldn't completely explain the behavior.

Comment: In my answer below I have a reference to the code that shows that second  `Http()` call does not have any side effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little source code investigation shows the following.

[Here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/0f2da7b26b5c4af35be87d2bd4a1a2392365df15/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/Http.scala#L780) we see what happens at `Http()` call. `Http` object extends `ExtensionId[HttpExt]` trait, which is responsible for registering additional functionality with actor system. 
[This](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/4acc1cca6a27be0ff80f801de3640f91343dce94/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Extension.scala#L79) is that `super` call. As we can see it uses `this` reference, which in our case in an object reference (important). 
[Here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/4acc1cca6a27be0ff80f801de3640f91343dce94/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSystem.scala#L731) is what actually happen when we call `Http()`. The first thing this code does is checking whether the extension is already registered. Remember, that `ext` in our case is an object, so any subsequent calls after first one won't do anything.

This means that either of your approaches would work the same, but imo using one `httpExt` is less confusing, given how the underlying system really works.